# How to store constants that can be read from all program, and also be used in defining functions?

Tags: c++, class, constants

I need to form a file named "constants.txt", and then use them when defining runge Funtion. Since the constants in the main function cannot be used outside the main function. How can I do about it?

Thanks!

```
float runge(float x, float y){
   return (-a*x+b*y+c/4.0+e*delta_t);} // where a,b,c,d,e,delta_t are from the file created
int main(){
    ofstream vOut("constants.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    vOut.precision(5);
    vOut << "1.22" 
            << setw(5) <<"9.81"
            << setw(4) <<"0.0"<<endl;
    vOut << "3.0"  
            << setw(4) <<"1.0" 
            << setw(6) <<"0.01"<<endl;  
    vOut.close();
    
    const float a, b, c;
    const float d, e, delta_t;
    
    //read the file and set variables
    ifstream vMyFile("constants.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while (vMyFile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> delta_t) {
    }
            vMyFile.close();
```

Comment: Create a class Constant with above value and initialize them from file. then pass that instance as extra argument to `runge` function?

Comment: You should ask your teaching staff what the intent of the assignment is. There are several ways this could be accomplished as stated. Passing a structure, reading the file over and over in `runge`, including `constants.txt` in the compilation (although this one seems weird).

Comment: So I need to include codes of reading the file in the class Constant, but can it read from the file that I created in the main function?

Comment: ***Since the constants in the main function cannot be used outside the main function.*** You can create a structure or class that you initialize its members in int main() and pass a pointer or constant reference to any function you call from main() giving the function access to the constants that you set in main

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to define a header file named like `constants.h`, which contains like

```cpp
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

static const float a = 1;
static const float b = 2;
static const float c = 3;
static const float d = 4;
static const float e = 5;
static const float delta_t = 1E-5;

#endif
```

Any `cpp` file can include the header and there is no worry about redifining these variables.